# Не работает this в стрелочной функции

Tags: javascript

```js
class Catalog {
    constructor(selector) {
        this.items = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
    }
    getBorder(event, callback) {
        this.items[0].addEventListener(event, callback);
    }
}
let catalog = new Catalog('.catalog__item');
catalog.getBorder('click', () => {this.style.border = "3px solid red"});
```

Почему при использовании стрелочной функции консоль выдаёт ошибку, а при синтаксисе function declaration всё отрабатывает как надо без ошибок?

Answer (score 1):

Потому что в стрелочной функции `this` - это контекст в том месте, где она определена. А в обычной, `this` зависит от того, как функция вызвана.

Answer (score 0):

у стрелочной функции this берется родительский там где она создана, так как не имеет своего.

Comment: А чем ваш ответ отличается от уже существующего?

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica Он отличается автором ответа.